# Swipe function for mobile version of website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does bootstrap provide a swipe functionality for the user to swipe slides or images?

If not, is their a easy approach to do this? I am a beginner in both javascript and coldfusion and would like any help that can take me to the right direction or where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Bootstrap does not provide such a function. I suggest using [ZingTouch](https://github.com/zingchart/zingtouch). Here is an example from their docs:

```
var parentTouchArea = document.getElementById('parent-toucharea')
var touchArea = document.getElementById('toucharea')
var myRegion = new ZingTouch.Region(parentTouchArea);

myRegion.bind(touchArea, 'swipe', function(e){
    console.log(e.detail);
});
```

Comment: I am looking at ZingTouch and what files should I use to just simply do swipping

Comment: @RobertoFlores The /dist folder in the repo contains a zingtouch.min.js file. That's all you would need to load.

Comment: @Jacques Marais:I have tried that but not sure where in coldfusion it would go

Answer (score 1):

You could try jQuery mobile, it has many great resources for (you guessed it) mobile and it is very easy to use, plus there are a lot of great tutorials online.

```
$(".elementClassName").on("swipe", function(){
    //jQuery or JS code here
});
```

Note that you need to have the script file for jQuery Mobile and jQuery (not sure about the latter though) for the code to run

Also, if your developing for iPhone or WebKit, you should give a look to scroll-snap, it works as you would expect using only CSS and no JavaScript. Check it out on this link
https://webkit.org/demos/scroll-snap/

Comment: Thank You, I will look into this and to the other recommendations

Comment: Base on what I am reading, it would be best to use scroll-snap. Seems to be usable for both iphone and for android correct

Comment: Sure, plus it also works on desktop (WebKit only)

Comment: So it would work fine on chrome, firefox, IE safari? I am reading it has no support for those browser minus firefox

Comment: Safari is based on WebKit, so it will run perfectly. It May in theory work in Chrome, since it is based on a modified version of WebKit. I don't know if it will work on Firefox and I doubt it will work on IE. However, in all others you will still be able to scroll. On iPhone, every browser is based on WebKit (whether you use Chrome, Firefox or Opera, the only thing that changes between this is the UI, but the rendering engine is the same)

Comment: So if I will go this route and display the carousel for example, I will be able to use my fingers to swipe the images, meaning I can swipe to the next image or swipe back to the previous image

Comment: I am not seeing how I can implement scroll-snap. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In the demo page, there are code snippets below each example; shall you have any further questions, I think there are other tutorials online. If there is anything more I can help you with, I'll be glad to

Comment: I do not see how I can implement it. I hate to ask but can you assist me on how to approach this problem

Comment: Sure, you need to know: the id or class of the parent element and that of the children, first... It is tricky at first... Maybe this link can help you. If you have any further questions, don't doubt on asking https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/

Answer (score 0):

Check out HammerJS: http://hammerjs.github.io/ -- it provides cross-browser abstractions for a lot of touch gestures, including swipe.

Comment: Just a word of warning with Hammer JS, it can at times brake div scrolling. I personally have come across this with Hammer.js. Don't get me wrong it was great when it was working but I had to remove due to it hijacking a horizontal scrolling div